# SyntaxError while trying to perform RobustScaler on Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, regression, scaling, kaggle

I am working with the `House Prices Kaggle dataset`. I am trying to use the `RobustScaler` from sklearn only on **numerical features** in the dataset (`LotFrontage`, `LotArea`, etc.). First, I fit the data to the numerical values of my dataframe by calling `select_dtypes(exclude=['object']`. Once the transformer has been fit to those values, I call the `transform` function, trying to transform those same values I just fit the data on by setting the transformer equal to object excluded attributes. Once I attempt that, I get the following error message:

> SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Data has already been rid of `null` values. What has worked is when I set the transform results equal to some variable, I get the results back as a `numpy.ndarray`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
transformer = RobustScaler().fit(df_train.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']))

df_train.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']) = transformer.transform(df_train.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])) # This doesn't work

test = transformer.transform(df_train.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])) # This DOES work, but not in the format I need
```

All I want is for the transformed attributes to go back into the original `pandas data frame` at their corresponding locations. Is there some workaround I can implement if I can't convert the original dataframe results directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work. Not sure how Pythonic this solution is, but it got me back on track:

```
df_train[list(df_train.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).columns)] = RobustScaler().fit_transform(df_train[list(df_train.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).columns)])
```